# Is casting string or reference type create another object in memory?

Tags: c#, string

Today I am reading [article](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/implement-icloneable-or-not) and article shows the code snippet:-

```
string s1 = "Something";
string s2 = (string)s1.Clone();
if ((object).ReferenceEquals(s1, s2))
     throw new Exception("But I need to know!");
```

Code snippet throws an error why? I can't understand what happened under a hood in CLR.
My question is a **string or reference type casting create a new object or not?**

Comment: *Always* say what the error is. "Code snippet throws an error" is *never* enough information.

Comment: Please bear in mind also that "throws an error" has a specific meaning in c#. Throwing an error is what the last line of that code attempts to do. What actually happens with the above code is that you get a compiler error which is not the same thing.

Comment: `Never` is almost never correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.clone(v=vs.110).aspx), It specifically states `The return value is not an independent copy of this instance; it is simply another view of the same data.`
and that `there is little reason to call it directly.`

So, in short the `Clone()` method does not create a new copy. Type casting does not influence the instance of the data in memory, it merely provides **another way** of interpreting the same data.

Comment: `So, in short the Clone() method does not create a new object.` Is the "not" there a mistake?  The quote from the link is specifically saying that it creates a new object...

Comment: By `object` i meant a copy! and the link says `the Clone method simply returns the existing string instance` that means it casts the contents as an object. which is similar to doing a `(object)string`. For the sake of clarity I will change it @Servy

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call a static method is to directly call that method on the type.  `class.Method()`.  By wrapping the type in parenthesis the compile considers this a cast of an instance.

Change this line ...

```
if ((object).ReferenceEquals(s1, s2))
```

... to this ...

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2))
```

Comment: Because of the error. `object` is a type `(object)` is a cast.